# How can I use a Javascript variable for a form action tag?

Tags: javascript, html

I have A sign-up form with a dropdown list and a script where I get the value of the selected option, I want to know if there is any way I can use the var selectedValue in the form action tag.

```js
function getSelectValue(){
      //var that i want to use in the form action tag
      var selectedValue = document.getElementById("User_type").value;
      console.log(selectedValue);
      

    }
```

```html
<!--Sign-up form--> 
<form class="modal-content animate" action="I WANT THE JS VAR HERE" on method = "POST">
        <div class="Logo">
          <h1>Logo</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="container-fluid">

          <div class="Name_field">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Enter First Name" name="first" required>
          </div>

          <div class="Username_field">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username/E-mail" name="username" required>
          </div>

          <div class="Password_field">
            <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="pwd" required>
          </div>

          <div class="ConfirmPassword_field">
              <input type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" name="pwd2" required>
          </div>
          <select id="User_type" name="User_type" onchange="getSelectValue();">
            <option value="0">Choose User</option>
            <option value="signupinc.php">USER1</option>
            <option value="signupinc1.php">USER2</option>
            <option value="signupinc2.php">USER3</option>
            <option value="signupinc3.php">USER4</option>
       </select>

          <div class= "Submit">
            <button type="submit" name="submit">Sign-up</button>
          </div>
          
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: put id to your form say "formid " and use script  $('#formId').attr('action', selectedValue);

Comment: You could probably update the attribute with the value using JS. I don't know how to do that with vanilla JS. There seems to be no PHP relation here. You also could process the whole form with AJAX.

Comment: That is an attribute like any other, so … where is the problem? If your basic question really just boils down to, “how do I set the value of an attribute of an HTML element via JavaScript” - then you should really do some proper research on that, before you come asking.

Comment: @SandeepModak That requires jquery. `document.getElementById` suggests OP isn't using jquery.

Comment: document.getElementById('formid').action = selectedValue; will do in javascript

Comment: glad to help. hope you understand the logic behind same.